# Will my futuristic homing tracker signal be lost inside a mountain?

Tags: technology, radio

My protagonist is being pursued, and they have put a tracker in his arm he cannot remove, lest it blow up and kill him. Pretty standard stuff. It's the future, so maybe the tracker is more sophisticated, but I assume in the end it's still some sort of radio signal. The bad guy has the receiver.

At some point, hero goes to a secret place inside a mountain. He's deep in the caverns, and high up.

Will being inside that mountain block the receiver from knowing where he is?

EDIT: There's just one receiver, one tracker device sending the signal. They really just need to find him either in town or in a wide open area like a desert.

Comment: My story isn't hard science fiction, so the details aren't too important. Assume a well made signal/receiver. The tracker in his arm is sending out the signal and has its own little power source. There's no base station. The rock is thick, they had to get into the center of it. It's hard rock, not soft.

Comment: Any organization that would do this would also probably put the explosive into a 'deadman's switch' configuration. As in, if the signal is ever lost, the explosive blows and the protagonist dies.

Comment: It's customary on Stack exchange to wait between 24-48 hours *minimum* to award the accepted answer, the many members in different time zones might just have offered a better answer. It's acceptable to withdraw the award, then re-issue it later when it's appropriate.

Comment: My cell phone can't even get reception in the garage under my office building...

Comment: @Confoundedbybeigefish. Thanks I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, unless there are receivers all over the place.

An implanted radio beacon will have only limited power, even with futuristic technology. This will not penetrate rock, and it will penetrate badly through caves or tunnels.

The enemies might be able to determine the hole in the ground where their fugitive vanished, and once they come close in the tunnels they might pick the signal up again.

Comment: Great. There's just one receiver, one tracker device sending the signal. They really just need to find him either in town or in a wide open area like a desert.

Comment: @MajorTom This information should have been supplied in the question, not in the comment on an answer. We don't deal in guesswork here. Please [edit] your question to reflect **all** the relevant information.